# How can I change the speed that my turtle rotates?

Tags: python, performance, rotation, turtle-graphics

I'm using turtle to draw a massive project but the turning takes years to do.

I have tried the command turtle.speed("fastest") but that only changes distance speed not rotational speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the [documentation for turtle](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.speed), it looks like `turtle.speed()` controls both speed and rotation:

> Speeds from 1 to 10 enforce increasingly faster animation of line drawing and turtle turning.

**Additionally**,

> speed = 0 means that no animation takes place. forward/back makes turtle jump and likewise left/right make the turtle turn instantly.

Note that `turtle.speed("fastest")` sets speed = 0. Maybe try changing speed to 10 with just `turtle.speed(10)` or `turtle.speed("fast")`.

Your current solution sounds like it should work, if you add some example code we might be able to better assist you in finding a solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can use turtle.speed(speed=None)
 where speed is an integer in the range 0.. 10 or a speedstring.

if the input is a number greater than 10 or smaller than 0.5, speed is set to 0.Speedstrings are mapped to speed values as follows:

"fastest":0

"fast":10

"normal":6

"slow":3

"slowest":1

speed from 1 to 10 enforce increasingly faster animation of line drawing and turtle turning.speed=0 means that no animation takes place.forward/back makes turtle jump and likewise left/right make the turtle turn instantly.

e.g:
     turtle.speed()

```
 turtle.speed(9)

 turtle.speed('normal')
```